# OpenCV - match SURF points runtime error

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection, surf

I have a program which matches feature points found in a template image to those shown in the video feed. When I run the program I am getting the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (i1 >= 0 && i1 < static_cast<int>(keypoints1.size())) in drawMatches, file bin/opencv-2.4.7/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp, line 207
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  bin/opencv-2.4.7/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp:207: error: (-215) i1 >= 0 && i1 < static_cast<int>(keypoints1.size()) in function drawMatches

Aborted
```

This is the function `drawMatches` that is mentioned above:

```
drawMatches(img_1, templateKeypoints, frames, keypoints_1, good_matches, img_matches, cv::Scalar::all(-1), cv::Scalar::all(-1), std::vector<char>(), cv::DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);
```

From what I've read I believe the problem is to do with if the feature points found in the video do not match the feature points in the template image then the program is aborting.

```
min_dist = 100;      
for(int i = 0; i < img_descriptors_1.rows; i++) {
        if(matches[i].distance <= 3 * min_dist) {
          good_matches.push_back(matches[i]);
        }
      }
```

I am looking for the video feed to run constantly even if no matches are present.

EDIT:

I've noticed if I repeatedly try to run the program I sometimes get an alternative error message:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (npoints >= 0 && points2.checkVector(2) == npoints && points1.type() == points2.type()) in findHomography, file /home/colin/bin/opencv-2.4.7/modules/calib3d/src/fundam.cpp, line 1074
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/colin/bin/opencv-2.4.7/modules/calib3d/src/fundam.cpp:1074: error: (-215) npoints >= 0 && points2.checkVector(2) == npoints && points1.type() == points2.type() in function findHomography

Aborted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just after the following:

```
extractor.compute(img_1, keypoints_1, descriptors_1);
extractor.compute(frame, keypoints_2, descriptors_2);
```

please add this:

```
if ((descriptors_1.empty()) || (descriptors_2.empty()))
continue;
```

Since no keypoints are found in the particular frame, it should go to the next iteration and check for a new frame. 
This solved my problem.

Comment: I'd already solved the problem and came up with the same solution. I've accepted your answer for any future people with the same problem.